# iPhoneX fullscreen without using storyboard (Using Objective C GLKViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I have an OpenGL Objective C App (based on a custom GLKViewController) without using storryboards (using xib files) and want to use the full resolution on the iPhoneX.
How can I achieve this?

[image]

I tried overloading `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and changing the origin of the view with no success.

Is it somehow possible to disable the safe area feature? I want to handle this in my OpenGL context.

I'm using launch images

[image]

Comment: FYI - the term "launchscreen images" is confusing. iOS either uses a "launch screen file (storyboard)" or it uses "launch images".

Comment: You should update your question with a clear description of the actual issue you are having. Perhaps a screenshot showing your problem.

Comment: I updated my question